# Ruby on rails server wont start due to a load error when trying to use svn_wc gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, rubygems

I am trying to get the svn_wc gem working in rails. It installs fine(via bundle install) but crashes the server when I launch it. I followed the instructions on the gem github page (https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc) and tried to install the svn bindings with the supplied command:

```
apt-get install libsvn-ruby
```

This version can no longer be found so I installed libsvn-ruby1.8 which installed fine.I am still getting the following error when trying to run the server

```
   enter chris@chris-VirtualBox:~/Dropbox/SQMT/rails/SQMT1$ rails s
/home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/svn_wc-0.0.6/lib/svn_wc.rb:20:in `require': cannot load such file -- svn/core (LoadError)
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/svn_wc-0.0.6/lib/svn_wc.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    from /home/chris/Dropbox/SQMT/rails/SQMT1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

It appears to be the 'svn/core' file that is the problem. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: I would be surprised if a gem that old with so little activity actually worked today.

Comment: Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: No sorry - I would not touch SVN with a 200ft pole.

Comment: Try https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=svn

Comment: Trust me I wouldn't touch it if Ididn't have to ! Thanks I will check that out!